# Why is my event handler showing target as null?

Tags: reactjs

Assume I have this code:

```
class todo extends React.component {

 handleChange = (e) => {
  console.log(e) // clicking on e => target shows null
  console.log(e.target.value) // shows data
 }


 render () {
  return (
    <div> <form> <input type="text" onClick={this.handleChange} /> </form> </div>
   )
 }

}
```

I don't understand why the event in the console log shows null if you just `conosole.log(e)`

but it shows data if I do `console.log(e.target.data)`

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Do you think you're running into this issue? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#Logging_objects

Comment: Hi, could you check my answer?

Comment: @SuleymanSah Your answer isn't correct. My question was about logging `e` not `e.target...`

Comment: you can also console.log(e), what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: if you do `console.log(e);` only and click on `target` you will see, `null` i was asking why

Comment: @tegradite, does my answer solve your problem?, is something more needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are logging an object reference. The browser devtools do not immediately render the object and its values, but evaluate it later. By that point the `target` has been removed from the event, react cleaning it up for hygiene reasons.

The advice from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#Logging_objects) is to JSONify the object and back.

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)))
```